# Новый блок для отзыва

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите: в файле **single-product.js** есть такой код:

```
// Star ratings for comments
.on( 'init', '#rating', function() {
  $( '#rating' ).hide().before( '<p class="stars"><span><a class="star-1" href="#">1</a><a class="star-2" href="#">2</a><a class="star-3" href="#">3</a><a class="star-4" href="#">4</a><a class="star-5" href="#">5</a></span></p>' );
})
```

Этот код скрывает список `select` и выводит вместо списка звёзды в новом блоке.

Как можно отменить это действие? Т.е. чтобы список `select` не скрывался, а новый блок не создавался.

Этот js-обработчик находится в папке с плагином [*woocommerce*](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/). Его нельзя переписывать, чтобы при обновлении плагина ничего не нарушилось.
Список `<select>`, который скрывается js-обработчиком, имеет такой вид:

```
<select name="rating" id="rating" aria-required="true" required style="display: none;">
```

Или подскажите, как можно заменить тот блок, который вставляет *js-обработчик* (`<p class="stars">...`)? Т.е., как вставить вместо этого `<p class="stars"...` другой блок, но чтобы учёт оценок товара остался работоспособным?

Как правильно заменить код отзыва на свой код и своё оформление?
Весь код находится в функции comment_form(), которой передаются параметры. Получается нужно полностью переопределять эту функцию?

Comment: убрать у него `id="rating"` ?

Comment: @teran
нет, нужно отменить скрытие списка <select>.
в результате вышеприведённого js-скрипта список select имеет такой вид:  (P.S.кстати как здесь поставить перевод на другую строку?)
    `<select name="rating" id="rating" aria-required="true" required="" style="display: none;">`

Comment: я в принципе понял, как выглядит код вашего `select`. Насколько критично ему иметь `id="rating"`, ибо только благодаря этому атрибуту он скрывается, и добавляются звездочки. Если удалите эту часть, то список останется исходным

Comment: @teran
а если  критично?

Comment: тогда добавьте ему ему класс `class="no-stars"`, а в обработчике исключите его `on('init', '#rating:not(.no-stars)', ..`

Comment: этот обработчик находится в папке с плагином woocommerce.
Его нельзя переписывать, чтобы при обновлении плагина ничего не нарушилось

Comment: тогда включите все вышеперечисленные требования в текст вашего вопроса, и ждите ответа :)

Comment: у кого какие идеи?

Comment: Вы так и не пояснили, почему нельзя `id="rating"` заменить на что-либо другое. И что значит "чтобы учет оценок оставался работоспособным".

Comment: хорошо, допустим заменили `id="rating"`, а ведь js-код вставляет совсем другой код с другими стилями. 
Поэтому я и спрашиваю, как правильно заменить код на другой, т.е. чтобы придать новый вид отзывам? В том коде, который вставляет js-скрипт нет такого: `id="rating"`. Отсюда и вопрос: как правильно заменить код отзыва на свой?

Comment: дополнил вопрос